# Grails create-app unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: grails

I have setup grails 3.2.1. on windows JAVA_HOME and GRAILS_HOME is also set. verified by running grails -version and worked as expected.

But when  issue command to create app, it always throw following error

"Error occurred running Grails CLI: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)".

I tried it by disconnecting the internet and come to know its trying to connect to https://repo.grails.org

It seems that some certificates must be in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts. with this thought I downloaded the SSL certificates from https://repo.grails.org by accessing the URL in browser.

same certificates imported in the JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts but still no change.

I could not find even a single related post over the internet.

when creating Grails app in Netbeans 8, I get the same error.

I don't know if I need any other valid certificate or there is any other problem.

Many thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to proxy server. i traced the network log. https://repo.grails.org resolves to proxy ip, I guess, because when i access the ip over htps in browser it presents me a certificate which really not in my keystore, when i add the same in my keystore an "host name mismatch error" is thrown instead of "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

i tried to run this at my home pc and it worked though there are other issues but good to go with next step to work on Grails.

Thanks

Comment: I see you've identified the problem. What is the workaround/solution to run this via proxy?

Comment: hi, it's long time back I was doing that. i did it from my home network instead of office but there is one option to set the proxy server mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 4):

Use the "HTTP version" repository

Add the following configuration in USER_HOME/.grails/settings.groovy:

```
grails {
    profiles {
        repositories {
            myRepo {
               url = "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you set up the grails.bat to use this instead of:

%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRAILS_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.grails.cli.GrailsCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

where using org.grails.cli.GrailsCli causes the proxy issue. I tried just putting the url there, but that didn't work.